# Sending emails with German Umlaut (äöü) in domain doesn't work with symfony 3.4

Tags: php, email, symfony-3.4

I'm trying to send emails with symfony 3.4 and when I'm sending to an email with German Umlaut in the domain like `mail@thomas.müller.de` - which since a while is actually an allowed format - I get the following error message:

> Address in mailbox given [mail@thomas.müller.de] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.

So ... yeah that sucks. Is there already a workaround, maybe a parameter that I can set? I do not really want to implement my own solution if there already is something (probably far better tested than my solution would ever be).

Comment: Have you tried `idn_to_ascii()` ?

Comment: What php version do you use? I think this was fixed in latest versions

Comment: php version 7.1